# Breakdown this jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first post to S\O and I'm trying to get my head around the following code and why it works so I can have a better understanding on how to implement my own code.

I'm going through the Odin Project and I'm stuck on creating a 16 x 16 grid. I choose to look at an example, but am unsure how it *fully* works.

Here's the code:

```
function createGrid(x) {
    for (var rows = 0; rows < x; rows++) {
        for (var columns = 0; columns < x; columns++) {
            $("#container").append("<div class='grid'></div>");
        };
    };
    $(".grid").width(640/x);
    $(".grid").height(640/x);
};
```

I don't understand why the bottom two lines are needed. I thought the loop would be enough to create the grid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two bottom lines divide the grid size in this case `640` on the number of rows to make each cell the right size.

Comment: The last two lines just set the width and height of each div. The grid exists, just not at any specific size until those lines.

Comment: Without the css, this will create single column of divs, not a grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last two lines simply reset the width and height of every DIV with a class of "grid" to 640 divided by the number of rows/columns the grid is creating.

Conceivably, <s>that bit of code</s> logic to set the height/width could have been included right after the .append() call, but this is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @DaniP i mean.. technically doing it one time at the end is actually looping through them yet again.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the call to $(selector).width() will still loop through every element matched in the selector assigning the width. Therefore, the performance is nearly identical. In fact, I would argue that if you wanted to include more than one grid on your page the original logic would mess up a previously rendered 3x3 grid were you to follow it up with a 6x6 grid.

Comment: @DaniP one time, *per grid cell.* which is exactly what would happen if you instead did it each time you appended each grid cell. it could even be *more* performant if you set the width in the same action as appending.

Comment: @DaniP - you are absolutely correct in that I misstated my intent (and have since updated my answer). I had to re-read it to see my mistake. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem that's why the comments are made , will delete mine to avoid the spam on your answer :)

Comment: @Forty3 if you were to do `$(".grid").each(function() { $(this).width(..); }` it would be slower because the browser would re-render after each width change.  By applying to `$(".grid").width()` the browser will redraw at the end as a single step (as I understand it, there's more info on SO somewhere)

Comment: *If* you're after the most browser efficient, then you'd change the css directly (which you can do via js), not apply a calculated width.  The better jquery would be to chain with height after the width rather than reselect.   But that seems to be offtopic :).

Comment: @freedomn-m - right, i was thinking more along the lines of `$("#container").append($("<div class='grid'></div>").width(640/x).height(640/x));` which would set it at the time of generation.